# SSRS-Report works few days and then i get error (Numeric data is not valid)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with over 15 datasets and the report was working fine for a while.Now in one of the datasets i get an error type 6 "Numeric Data is not valid".My database is AS400 and i am fetching data from a view.The column where the problem was initially character,so i changed it to decimal .The report worked for 2 days without a problem then i got same error .Then i played around with the query and just changed the order of some input parameters ,the report again worked for a day without a problem .But now it shows the same error after a day .Every time i change something the report works for a day or two and then gives same numeric error data.

My query is

```
      SELECT        SLYEAR, STATUS, SLMONTH, SUM(TOTALDLVR) AS TOTALDLVR
  FROM            VEHICLE.VHVSALETR4
   WHERE        (SLFRAN = ?) AND (SLDPCD = ?) AND (SLSMCD IN
                                (SELECT        WEMEMCD
                                  FROM            VEHICLE.VHTEMPL 
   VHTEMPL_1
                           WHERE        (WEMEMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMTLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMTCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMBCMCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHOTLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHOGLCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMHHODCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMBHCD = ?) OR
                                                     (WEMGHODCD = ?)))
    GROUP BY SLYEAR, STATUS, SLMONTH
```

The problem was initiallly with WEMBHCD so i changed its order ,report worked for a day ,now the problem is in the place where it was replaced with WEMTCMCD

This field is an employee code ,and it is numeric value

Comment: can you show us some sample data. I think field `employee code` not always return number, it might be some characters as well.

Comment: the employee code is between 1000 and 99999 ,i ran a query to get total count in view ,then i ran a query with condition when employee code between 0 and 99999.Both the count values are same and match

Comment: hmm can you show the design of your report and particular column where you are facing issue

Comment: hi, the design column doesnt have salesman code anywhere.I am manipulating the employee code in parameter field in f(x) though  .I have however changed my view ,all input parameters for Employee code to character .I tested the application thoroughly and it is working as of now .I have to see after a day or two if it works or not

Comment: my f(x) function is =IIF(Parameters!PRSalesMan.Value <> 
"ALL",Parameters!PRSalesMan.Value,Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value)    Generally if condition is ALL it is working successfully,so i thought  this is the problem Parameters!PRSalesManCode.Value ,so i made everything related to employee code as character or text

Comment: @AnkUser the behaviour is same for the report ,it works 2-3 days then i get the same error ,if i just keep on clicking view report in report viewer  more times sometimes the report works and sometimes it throws the same error.I have to keep on swapping the query parameter position and the cycle continues